# How to center text in main div block

Tags: html, css

Here's what I got. I'm trying to center `pandora`, `rocket league` and `chess.com` in the `#header` div. Right now they're on the left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="abc.css"/>

<div id="top"></div>

<div id="header">
    <div class="hovimg">
        <a href="https://www.chess.com">
            Chess.com
            <span>
                <img src="https://tmp-m.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/chess.jpg" height="100px" width="180px"/>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="hovimg">
        <a href="https://www.pandora.com">
            Pandora
            <span>
                <img src="https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pandora-rebrand-980x420.png" height="100px" width="150px"/>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="hovimg">
        <a href="steam://rungameid/252950">
            Rocket League
            <span>
                <img src="http://static5.gamespot.com/uploads/screen_kubrick/1551/15511094/2999833-20141023_rocketleague_01.jpg" height="120px" width="200"/>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="left"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little stuck trying to figure out exactly what you're after, but here's one solution that may be what you're after:

```
.header:after { /* Clearfix */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.hovimg {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  float: left;
}
```

**Note:** Has not been tested, so it is possible this may not work, however at least the theory behind this idea should be of use.

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Not completely sure why though. I don't get what the content "" means and why you cleared both on header. Please explain, thanks.

Comment: @DanielArchuleta The styles under `.header:after` are those for clearfix. When you float an element, it's parent needs to be cleared to ensure the flow of the document doesn't break. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) for more info.

Comment: @DanielArchuleta Mind me asking you to mark this as successfully answering your question? It would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's what you are looking for.

```
<div id="header" style="text-align:center">
```

This will center the content of the header division.
If you want to add it to your CSS:

```
#header{
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all content in the center then you can apply `text-align: center` to `#header`.

Comment: This still didn't work. I think it's cuz it's not the text in between the initial div's but it's text of the <a> tag. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.hovimg { text-align: center; }
```

That's the class of the block elements your `a` tags, spans and images (which are inline elements by default) are in - it should center them (all together - they are in one line).